# Can (py)spark save metadata corectly with empty partitioned dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a problem with spark and saving empty pratitioned dataframe. There is an empty dataframe:

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('firstname', StringType()),
    StructField('middlename', StringType()),
    StructField('lastname', StringType())
])
empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema)
```

If I save it without partitioning

```
empty_df.write.mode('overwrite').format("parquet").save("/nonpartitioned_empty_df")
```

then parquet can be read without any errors (metadata is saved correctly).

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tot7n.png)

But if I try saving it with partitioning, for example:

```
empty_df.write.mode('overwrite').format("parquet").partitionBy("firstname").save("/partitioned_empty_df")
```

then analysis exception is thrown which indicates that metadata is not saved correctly:

```
AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.
```

Additionally in nonpartitioned_empty_df path we can see some files (one parquet, _committed, _started and _SUCCESS) in partitioned_empty_df there is only one file (_SUCCESS).

Is there any option to prevent that situation and to save empty partitioned parquet which can be read in the future?

Comment: What's the use case of having an empty partitioned file

Comment: why don't you provide the schema yourself while reading ?

Comment: @Manakin It reads data from database and saves to a storage. Other pipeline (created with azure data factory) reads from the storage and process that. If dataframe is empty pipeline works, in case of this error pipeline fails. I have to prevent that error.

Comment: @AdityaVikramSingh Here I showed only an exmaple of this problem. In my real case I read data from multiple tables (database), process and save them. So I don't know if it is possible.